# How do I profile the startup process in OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, mac, performance, boot, benchmarking

When I bought my MBP 2.2 GHZ in 2007, it got from dead to an active dock in about 18 seconds, and now it takes about 1:30 to get a fully responsive home screen.

I want to find a way to profile the various things it does when it starts up so I can begin tuning it a bit.

Any good software or other recommendations for this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you start by browsing the /var/log/system.log messages from the times of the last couple boots and see if anything jumps out at you. Then reboot and immediately hold down Cmd-V (verbose boot) at boot time and see what gets logged to the screen immediately before and immediately after any long pauses.

Let us know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling? No. Finding out what kind of junk you've got installed that's running itself when you aren't looking, yes:

http://khiltd.com/software/consultants_canary